# How to automatically select best result from try_all_threshold?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, image-preprocessing, image-thresholding

I am applying thresholding on a text-digit based image. Using `skimage.filters.try_all_threshold` results in 7 of thresholding algorithms getting applied. I am able to get the resut but I am thinking on how I can choose only 1 result to pass the result to next process/dynamically choose 1 best result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a **measure of similarity** between the original image and the binarized images, and then select the thresholding method that maximizes that measure.

#### Demo

The following code simply aims at putting you on the right track. Notice that the function `similarity` returns a random number rather than a sensible similarity measure. You should implement it on your own or replace it by an appropriate function.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.data import text
import skimage.filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

threshold_methods = [skimage.filters.threshold_otsu,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_yen,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_isodata,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_li,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_mean,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_minimum,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_mean,
                     skimage.filters.threshold_triangle,
                     ]

def similarity(img, threshold_method):
    """Similarity measure between the original image img and and the
    result of applying threshold_method to it.
    """
    return np.random.random()

results = np.asarray([similarity(text(), f) for f in threshold_methods])    
best_index = np.nonzero(results == results.min())[0][0]    
best_method = thresholding_methods[best_index]
threshold = best_method(text())
binary = text() >= threshold

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(binary, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title(best_method.__name__)
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: isodata]

#### Edit

Obviously, it makes nonsense to choose the thresholding method randomly (as I did in the toy example above). Instead, you should implement a similarity measure which allows you to automatically select the most efficient  algorithm. One possible way to do so would consist in computing the **misclassification error**, i.e. the percentage of background pixels wrongly assigned to foreground, and conversely, foreground pixels wrongly assigned to background. As the misclassification error is a disimilarity measure rather than a similarity measure, you have to select the method that minimizes that measure like this:

```
best_index = np.nonzero(results == results.min())[0][0]
```

Take a look at [this paper](http://pequan.lip6.fr/%7Ebereziat/pima/2012/seuillage/sezgin04.pdf) for details on this and other approaches to thresholding performance assessment.

Comment: can i define `measure of similarity `  as any random value ?  when i am saving the binarized  image it's coming as a whole black image am i doing something wrong ?